# Code::Blocks - Process Returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005)

Tags: c++

I don't understand what this line of text is referring to "Process Returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005".

[CMD Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43rmU.jpg)

It is coincident with the following warning in my log:

[Log Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Welrt.jpg)

"Warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]"

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

float milesToKm(float distance)
{
return distance*1.60934;
}

float milesToKm_(float& distance)
{
distance = distance*1.60934;
}


int main()
{
float distance;
cout << "Enter the distance in miles \n";
cin >> distance;

cout << "\nDistance in km is : " << distance*1.60934 ;
cout << "\nDistance in km is : " << milesToKm(distance) ;

milesToKm_(distance);


cout << "\nDistance in km is : " << distance;
return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain what this means to me? Do so the same way you'd explain it to a lobotomized Australian Dung Beetle

I copied this code into Code::Blocks, I was not expecting a warning on line 12. I am also not entirely sure if the prior "Process Returned" text is related to it.

Comment: The warning is because of `milesToKm_`. It has a return type of `float` but returns nothing.

Comment: Not returning a value from a function declared to return a value leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: *"Do so the same way you'd explain it to a lobotomized Australian Dung Beetle"* -- You mean by ignoring the beetle? Because last I checked, beetles did not have the brain capacity to know how to spell "return", to know what a function is, or to recognize that `float` is a different word than `void`. So not worth the time and effort to explain this error message to one. How are you at those three topics? Better than a dung beetle?

Answer (score 2):

`Process returned 0xc0000005` means it has crashed with an Access Violation.

Why would this code crash?

The warning ":12:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]" sounds like gcc, so assuming that.

Let's look at the disassembly: https://godbolt.org/z/1x7vadoj7

```
milesToKm_(float&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        //middle stuff removed
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        ud2
```

Now `ud2` is an interesting instruction. This is an explicit undefined instruction that, if reached, will produce an illegal instruction exception and crash the process.

That's right, gcc made sure that if you fall off the end of the function without returning the `float` value you promised, your program will crash.

If you enable optimizations with `-O2`, something even more worrying happens:

```
milesToKm_(float&):
        cvtss2sd        xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cvtsd2ss        xmm0, xmm0
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
.LC1:
        .string "Enter the distance in miles \n"
.LC2:
        .string "\nDistance in km is : "
```

The control just falls off the end of the function (as there is no RET instruction) and the CPU starts executing some strings or whatever happens to be in the memory above.

The "no return statement" warning may be somewhat survivable in C mode, in C++ this is almost always an error. I would recommend to add `-Werror=return-type` to your compile options for C++ to treat it as the error it is.

So how do you make it not crash? If you're not interested in returning a value, declare the function `void`:

```
void milesToKm_(float& distance)
{
distance = distance*1.60934;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I am using the GNU GCC Compiler with Code::blocks. The godbolt compiler explorer is a neat find. I also found out what I think I was doing incorrectly, among mis-copying the code, I was attempting to compile two .cpp files within the same project. I deleted one of them and the compilation was successful.